# Retrain last inception layer to work with smaller INPUT_SIZE

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

Retrain inception (there is no paramaeters, just path for our own image data):

https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/how_tos/image_retraining/

For mobilenet is said that the input image size could be '224', '192', '160', or '128' (for retraining purpose):

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py#L80

What about inception models? Can I somehow retrain inception model (its last layer like for mobilenet) to work with smaller (different) image input sizes (to get results faster)?

Comment: I don't think there is an automatic tool to take a model designed for a different image size (say, a larger one) and downsize the model. You would probably find it easiest to start from a trained model that accepts the correct input size.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [tf.image.resize_images](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/resize_images) to match the required input size of Inception.

Comment: no, you didn't understand, I want to get results faster (so net should work with smaller inputs, not resizing), there is no point resize my input image